# Adding specific URL to BASE PATH in order to scrape webpage using Nokogiri

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I am new to ruby and this site so please bear with me! I have googled endlessly to no fruition.

I am trying to pass in a `college` object to my class method `scrape_college_info` that I created in the previous class method `scrape_illinois_index_page`, so that I may scrape the next level of information for the specific college the user selects using Pry and Nokogiri. Unfortunately, I keep getting an argument error.

I know it isn't the prettiest, but this is my code right now:

```
    class College
  attr_accessor :name, :location, :size, :type, :url
  BASE_PATH = "https://www.collegesimply.com/colleges/illinois/"

  def self.college
    self.scrape_colleges
  end

  def self.scrape_colleges
    colleges = self.scrape_illinois_index_page

    colleges
  end

  def self.scrape_illinois_index_page
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(BASE_PATH))

    # binding.pry

    colleges = []

    doc.xpath("//tr").each do |doc|
      college = self.new
      if doc.css("td")[0] != nil
        college.name = doc.css("td")[0].text.strip
      end

      if doc.css("td")[1] != nil
        college.location = doc.css("td")[1].text.strip
      end

      if doc.css('table.table tbody tr td:nth-child(1) a')[0] != nil
        college.link = doc.css('table.table tbody tr td:nth-child(1) a')[0]['href']
      end
      colleges << college
    end
    colleges
  end

  def self.scrape_college_info(college)
    doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(BASE_PATH + "#{college.link}"))
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you share your exact error ?

Comment: What command are you entering to get the error?  Also please post full stack trace of your error.  I ran `College.college` and got no error.  Also you don't need `colleges = ` or the 2 lines after it I don't think in `scrape_colleges` method.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! So within my console I run my console by entering ./bin/console, and once inside console I am entering College.scrape_college_info to try to access my pry.

Comment: The exact error I am getting looks like this: [17:11:44] (master) illinois-colleges
// ♥ ./bin/console
2.3.1 :001 > College.scrape_college_info(college)
NameError: undefined local variable or method `college' for main:Object
        from (irb):1
        from ./bin/console:14:in `<main>'

Answer (score 1):

Try below code to get `college.link`.

```
if doc.css("td")[0] != nil
   college.name = doc.css("td")[0].text.strip
   college.link = doc.css("td")[0].css("a").map{|a| a['href']}[0]
end
```

Now you can pass college link like :

```
def self.scrape_college_info(college)
  doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("https://www.collegesimply.com" + "#{college.link}"))
end
```

Hope this will solve your problem. Please let me know, if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `URI.join`:

```
new_url = URI.join(BASE_PATH, college.link).to_s
```